# Include fields/projections from external schema in a graphql projections

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, graphql-codegen

I have a below type defined in my graphql schema in a maven project A

```
type Rule {
    name: String!
    additionalAttributes: Attribute
}
```

Here Attribute is defined in another graphql schema as below in a maven project B

```
 type Attribute {
    key: String
    value: String
}
```

Project B is added as a maven dependency in Project A.

I am using `io.github.deweyjose: graphqlcodegen-maven-plugin` to generate client in project B.

projection generated for `Rule` is as below:

```
public RulesProjection additionalAttributes() {
        this.getFields().put("additionalAttributes", (Object)null);
        return this;
    }
```

The above projection does not contain reference to external field ie `Attribue`.
How can I include `Attribute` related projection in Rule's projection?